# Don't clone newer tags in a repository

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a lot of repositories cloned, so I've made a script that checks if the expected tag is the same as the one I have. If not, it will `git pull origin newtag`. But sometimes the expected tag is older than the last tag in the remote, even though there isn't any change between both tags (but the new tag was created because other repos received changes). But with that git pull, I'm getting the newest tag, and not the expected one. So the script will `git pull origin newtag` again, even though I already have it. To check the current tag I'm in I use `git describe --tags --exact-match`

Comment: I'm not clear on your workflow… What do you mean by "newest tag" and "expected tag"? Are you moving tags around in your repository?

Comment: Last version I had cloned was, for example, r4. Now I wan't to go to r11, but last tag in the remote is r12. How can I go to r11, as `git pull origin r11` gets me to r12

Comment: Why would `git pull origin r11` get you to `r12`? Are `r4` and `r11` tags? Maybe you can [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: `git clone -b android-8.0.0_r4 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint`. Then, when you execute `git describe --tags --exact-match`, you get android-8.0.0_r12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR: just don't fetch again

If you avoid fetching, you'll avoid picking up new names for existing commits.  If that's not suitable you will just have to save the tag name yourself somewhere.  If you find a new tag, you can detect that it points to the same commit by using `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse android-8.0.0_r4^{commit}
git rev-parse android-8.0.0_r12^{commit}
```

would produce the same hash here.

#### Long description

Tags don't necessarily have ages—Git's "annotated tags" do have a timestamp but lightweight tags just add a new name for an existing commit and have no timestamp of their own—and even if they do, a single linear measure rarely suffices when dealing with branching.

> `git clone -b android-8.0.0_r4 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint`

In your particular example, if we go look at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint, we find that tags `8.0.0_r4` and `8.0.0_r12` are annotated tags, but literally point to the same commit, `4fcacd3d193f1e1dfb0f5a9e818dd895eca45427`.

The tag `8.0.0_r11` also points to this same commit (click on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint/+/android-8.0.0_r11 to see; change `r11` to `r4` or `r8` to see each annotated tag in their chosen web-page-display-format).

In other words, it doesn't matter which of these tags you check out: you get the same source code for all three of them.  If you want to remember which tag you used to do the `git checkout` operation—the final step of the `git clone` in your example—you must save it yourself somewhere.  Git saves, instead, the fact that this checked out commit `4fcacd3d193f1e1dfb0f5a9e818dd895eca45427`, and `git describe --tags` looks for a tag that leads to `4fcacd3d193f1e1dfb0f5a9e818dd895eca45427`.  It finds many, and picks one.  Here, it does use the annotated tag date if it's looking at annotated tags.

Whenever you run `git fetch` (the first half of `git pull`), Git obtains new objects; that may include new tags.  The main way to avoid picking up new tags (of any type, lightweight or annotated) is to avoid fetching.

If it's too late to avoid picking up new tags, note that you can look at *all* the tags (or all the annotated tags) by using `git for-each-ref refs/tags` and resolving each tag to its target object (usually a commit), or specifically to a commit (which fails if the tag points to some other object type, after perhaps following it through previous tags).

Comment: Before comparing the commits, what command I execute to get the new tags, without the new changes? And if they are the same, how can I delete all the unnecessary tags?

Comment: It's very hard to get rid of tags—they just keep coming back. But you can make a list of all the tags you have before running `git fetch`, and all the tags you have afterward; any that you have after, that you did not have before, came in because of the `fetch`. Note that `git fetch` is quite safe to do any time in general, as it merely adds to your repository's collection of commits, tags, and other objects *without touching your work-tree at all*.